# Swift dynamic table text goes outside cell width

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, prototype, cell

i just created a uitable view with dynamic cells, and as you can see with the insets, the cells have a correct width. But as shown on the image, the label goes out of the screen. I've set truncate tail, fixed font size... I can't manage to get this text truncated.

Should i do it programatically when creating the cell.text.value?

Help is very much appreciated here.
[image]

Comment: Did you set a Trailing constraint on your label?

Comment: the label is inside a stack view which has all constraints needed... yes

Comment: Are you *sure* the stack view has all the constraints needed? It looks like you have not set a Trailing constraint on the stack view.

Comment: @DonMag, yes... they're set...

Comment: OK - if they are set, then how is the label extending past the right edge? And the right-justified label *also* looks like it's past the right edge, which would *also* indicate that a trailing constraint is missing.

Answer (score 0):

You might not have set frame in LayoutSubviews(). Initially when tableviewcell loads it always gives same width value but when layoutSubviews gets called it gives correct frame.

If you have done it in storyboard then you might have given hardcoded value.

Comment: All the layout you see come from an autolayout in the storyboard using stacks, what do you suggest i should do exactly? Thank you man

Comment: I would suggest use auto layout based on your needs, suggested ones are always not enough and brings complexity in long run.

Comment: how to set frame in LayoutSubviews() ?

Comment: class SampleCell: UITableViewCell {
    var label: UILabel?
    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        label = UILabel()
        label?.text = "Hi"
        self.contentView.addSubview(label!)
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        label?.frame = CGRect.init(x: 10, y: 10, width: self.contentView.frame.size.width-20, height: self.contentView.frame.size.height-20)
    }
  
}

Answer (score 0):

Use Custom TableViewCell's

You can design the way you want and also you can set label/title width height font etc easily .

Make sure you register your tableview cell in viewdidload() or else it will crash

Comment: here you go...

[link](https://makeapppie.com/2016/10/17/custom-table-view-cells-in-swift-3/)

play with it

Comment: Well... i already use a custom cell... :-) so the issu resides somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two stack views, each with the same content - the text of the top label is `this is a really long label that will extend past the right edge`

The top one does ***not*** have a Trailing constraint.

The bottom one ***does*** have a Trailing constraint of `8`.

[image]

That *really* looks like the issue you are running into.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue.  Initially i had dropped a table view inside the view controller and set the prototype cell to 1 in IBinspector. For an unknown reason, the constraints were not working. Ended up setting protoype cells to 0 and dropping a new table view cell from the object library.

That did the trick.